# Groovy script to import testsuite into SoapUI Project and run it using testRunner

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am from QA and new to groovy and SoapUI pro Tool.
MY Requirement is to import a test suite from external location inside the SOapUI Tool inside the specific project and then run the test Suite using test Runner.

I have to achieve this all through groovy scripting.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Noone is going to write for you here. You try your hand to solve the problem and then ask what problem you are facing.

Comment: What did you try? what do you mean by import test suite from external location? why do you want to do that? what happens if the current project does not the service and its operations not available which is being used in the external test suite that you are talking? Why are you making so complex?

Comment: Hi Nipun,Sorry  but I was not getting any code to check or start with else I would have surely worked on it at initial stage and then posted it here.

Comment: Hi Rao,  what I have done is I have exported all the test suites of Project 
 named as "X" which was present in SoapUI to  location in D Drive . My objective is to write a groovy script to ready any specific Testsuite XML  from that location in D Drive and import it to SoapUI Tool and using TestRunner , run the testsuite and after running it again delete the TestSuite from inside the SoapUI .  We are trying to  do this for making our project completely Data Driven  which can be handled from Master Excel Sheet where only name of test suite with Flag value as "True" or "False " is determined.